# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Espresso Test when including Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric, android-espresso

I am trying to introduce Robolectric to an already existing android project. The project already runs a slew of espresso tests. As soon as I try to introduce robolectric, the tests fail with

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

Anyone have any thoughts? I'm using the gradle file below and used the [Decard](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) project as an example on brining in Robolectric.

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/signing.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/build_extras.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/environments.gradle"

loadConfiguration()

apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/checkstyle.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/pmd.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/findbugs.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/espresso.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'

    useOldManifestMerger true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ‘com.example.app'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode getVersionCode()
        testInstrumentationRunner 'com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }

    jacoco {
        version = '0.6.2.201302030002'
    }

    sourceSets {

        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')

    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        removeSetAnimationScaleFromManifest(variant)

        task("generate${variant.name}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
            description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
            group "Code Quality"

            def Properties localProperties = loadPropertiesFile('../local.properties')

            source = variant.javaCompile.source
            classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) +
                    files(localProperties['sdk.dir'] + "/platforms/android-4.4.2/android.jar")
        }

        copyAndRenameZipAlignedPackage(variant)
    }
}

apply plugin: 'monkey'

monkey {
    teamCityLog = false
    eventCount = 5000
    seed = 42
    failOnFailure = false
    install = false
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile project(':SlidingMenuLibrary')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    compile 'org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:0.6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.6.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.9.3'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:5.9'

    // Espresso
    provided 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
    androidTestCompile ('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') {

    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    //androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}
```

ErrorLog:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/android/ui/GettingStarted

...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:222)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:215)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:322)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
```

Comment: Please paste error logs to look at class name.

Comment: @Sachin Thapa - done. Notice it's complaining about a class in my project called GettingStarted. Removing Robolectric from gradle fixes that error. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you have a class compiled into your test APK AND you app APK.

Run ./gradlew :app:dependencies and look for duplicates.

You may need to use "provided" instead of "compile" somewhere.

This has been discussed in lots of places:

http://www.sinking.in/blog/android-dependency-double-trouble/

[java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation getting while running test project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155340/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-class-ref-in-pre-verified-class-resolved-to-unexpe)

https://www.google.com/#q=java.lang.IllegalAccessError%3A+Class+ref+in+pre-verified+class+resolved+to+unexpected+implementation

Comment: I was able to make the fix by removing the robolectric tests from the same folder as the espresso test. Sticking the robolectric tests outside of the app folder (using gradle folder structure). However, I'm marking this as the correct answer because the links help answer this specific question.