# Green dao not able to create classes when Enabling multidex support in android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, greendao, android-multidex, greendao-generator

As soon as enable multidex support in the `build.gradle` I am getting the following error on app launch.

```
    Could not find class '...Dao', referenced from method com.dao.DaoMaster.<init>

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/dao/DaoMaster
            at com.dao.DaoMaster$OpenHelper.onCreate(DaoMaster.java:57)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26721646/1247248) helped me figure out a solution.

To fix this problem I changed

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
```

to

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```