# Generate MainDexList.txt for Pre-5.0 Multidex app with reflection support

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin, android-multidex

We are using android-maven-plugin to build a [multidex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) application targeting Jelly Bean (4.3.x) with greater than 65k methods. The approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657974/2103033) helps create a MainDexList.txt file, but does not automatically include classes that will be loaded by reflection.

Are any tools or processes available that can create a MainDexList.txt file with reflection support? [The majority of the classes we are loading via reflection are named via String constants...]

We are attempting to avoid manually running the app and dealing with `NoClassDefFoundError` messages one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the `NoClassDefFoundError`, you just need to add the `MainDexList.txt` to each of your projects. This should solve your initial errors right away. However, since your `MainDexList.txt` will still be empty, you will run into further issues.

To load the `MainDexList.txt` with a script instead of doing it manually, you can use this open source script by Google which will generate the exact class names that should be included in `MainDexList.txt`. Here is a link to the actual commit by Google:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/2bb6fe45bf620525ba34bd7303d7ecb597aa0689

To learn more (and also my source of information):

http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/generating-main-dex-list-file.html

**Notes**: This unfortunately does not support reflection however, [DexClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) loads classes from `.jar` and `.apk` files containing a classes.dex entry. This may be worth looking at as well.

Hope this helps!