# NoClassDefFoundError on anonymous and static nested classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I have encountered an NoClassDefFoundError on my nested static and anonymous classes in my application. The point is, that this happens not on every device that i  have tested. I have read lots of stackoverflow and google trying to solve this issue, but still i cant get why it's happening on Zenphone 5 and Galaxy Tab E (android 4.4.4) but never happens on nexus 7/10 or on any other device with Android 5+.

I also tried to move all nested classes out of base class into their own .java files, and this helps, but i want to understand the root problem and fix it.

P.S. is possible, that this issue related with multidex support ?

**UPD 1**

LogCat:

> 02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/CrashlyticsCore: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/CrashlyticsCore:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:173)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/CrashlyticsCore:     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.executeSyncLoggingException(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:44)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/CrashlyticsCore:     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:245)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/CrashlyticsCore:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/CrashlyticsCore:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/CrashlyticsCore:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111: Error inflating class cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker.widget.HorizontalListView.HorizontalListView
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111: Error inflating class cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker.widget.HorizontalListView.HorizontalListView
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:268)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1968)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5303)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:268) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1968) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5303) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker.widget.HorizontalListView.HorizontalListView$2
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker.widget.HorizontalListView.HorizontalListView.(HorizontalListView.java:365)
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:268) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1968) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5303) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>   02-29 17:09:43.306 28749-28749/cinamaker.nlt.com.cinamaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Code:
I dont want to add the whole class here, it's to big. I'm adding only currently active issue.

```
public class HorizonatlListView {

  ...

   private DataSetObserver mAdapterDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        mDataChanged = true;

        // Clear so we can notify again as we run out of data
        mHasNotifiedRunningLowOnData = false;

        unpressTouchedChild();

        // Invalidate and request layout to force this view to completely redraw itself
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        // Clear so we can notify again as we run out of data
        mHasNotifiedRunningLowOnData = false;

        unpressTouchedChild();
        reset();

        // Invalidate and request layout to force this view to completely redraw itself
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
   };

    ...

}
```

Comment: Post your code and logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not happens on API 21+ because multidexing needed only for Dalvik. ART doesn't have an 65536 methods limit. So, it's happens because your classes goes out from main dex file. 
Maybe it will useful for you:
1) http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/generating-main-dex-list-file.html
2)[MultiDex NoClassDefFound error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655541/multidex-noclassdeffound-error)