# app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug exception and java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: android, exception, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle

I am getting below Error while running my Application.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

I think the issue is with my .gradle file. Maybe some duplication for dependency in my .gradle file. I have removed one but, still getting the error.

My .gradle file is as below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackagename"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.+'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
}
}
```

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mypackagename">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.roadysmart.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UserProfileEditActivity"
        android:label="User Profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SignInActivity"
        android:label="Sign In"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectActivity"
        android:label="Were here to help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:label="Sign Up"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="Forgot Password"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UserProfileActivity"
        android:label="User Profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaS0000000014789occURS5KvtKgfdreWjaDI" />

</application>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MultiDex NoClassDefFound error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655541/multidex-noclassdeffound-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` in `defaultConfig`.

Moreover, its not recommended to use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2` directly rather include the dependencies you want to work with  separately. Like if you want to work with Google Maps, then add only `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.1.0` and so on.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

`com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`

You've hit the [dex limit](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) for the number of methods that can be used in which affects all device lower than `Android 5.0(21)`.

To fix this you need to enable multi-dex in your gradle and have your application extends `MultiDexApplication` to work around with the max Dex limit.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```