# Moving file in Android Studio - java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When moving a package in Android Studio I received this message:

[image]

I hit 'Move all'  Now my unit tests fail with

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
```

And then blows up on a class that was moved.  Any idea why this is or how to fix it?  I has to be including it twice in my apk.  I've search for any reference of the file (even tried renaming it, deleting it adding back in etc etc)  Nothing works.

Comment: Try some solution from these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11155340/1291150, seems to be the same problem

Comment: It isn't.  Everything is fine.  I move the package, boom blows up.  No other changes