# XAMARIN - Mono.Android - Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Tags: c#, xamarin, dll, ilrepack

I've used ILRepack to merge a bunch of DLLs into a final Merged.dll with

```
ILRepack.exe /verbose /out:C:\..\.Merged.dll /wildcards *.dll /lib:C:\.MonoAndroidPath.\v8.1
```

Some of the merged DLLs use Mono.Android.dll functionality and I do not want to merge that in as I believe it to be wrong and also the output assembly will go at ~30MB.

That's why instead of merging it I used the `/lib` feature of ILRepack to specify a reference.
`/lib:C:\.MonoAndroidPath.\v8.1` is the path to the Mono.Android.dll also used by the xamarin solution.

When I use the `Merged.dll` in the app, it does compile but when the app is about to start I get

> Java.Lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Is there any way to solve this?

The solution does work if all of the DLLs are added separately.

Edit:

[java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation getting while running test project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155340/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-class-ref-in-pre-verified-class-resolved-to-unexpe)

I did read through this post and similar ones, but they relate to an Android solution and not to a Xamarin solution. I couldn't translate so far the solution provided there to my case. So please do not close this question as it is still relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation getting while running test project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155340/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-class-ref-in-pre-verified-class-resolved-to-unexpe)

Comment: @Stefan did read around that post, but it has to do more with an Android solution and not a Xamarin one. I did not find a way to solve it by translating what was being discussed there in C#

Comment: Hmm.. yes, I see. Nevertheless, the error seems to indicate that there is a duplicate reference. Can you verify that?

Comment: It does indicate that, and in theory it might be as I'm not fully aware of what the `/lib` functionality of ILRepack does. The Xamarin.Android solution does have a reference to the Mono.Android.dll project as mentioned in the post, but the same path to that reference is defined in the `/lib` command. What I believe to be the solution is to somehow specify in the .csproj that the first working reference to the Mono.Android.dll found to be the one used, but haven't found a way to do that so far.